# MS Excel XML Header Footer

Tags: xml, excel, coldfusion, ms-office

I'm generating a excel report in a XML Excel format. In this report I have to repeat the top 25 rows and bottom 10 rows on each page, like a header and a footer. Can you please guide me on the code that is required to accomplish this task. I'm using ColdFusion. Thank you.

Ravi

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the cfinclude tag like this

```
<cfinclude template="./header.xml" />
```